# Draftjs toolbar loses formatting state when Editor is focused

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, draftjs, react-draft-wysiwyg

I'm using `draft-js` and `react-draft-wysiwyg` to build a rich text editor but I'm having an issue.
Before interacting with the `Editor`, if you enable bold/italic before typing and focus the `Editor`, the bold/italic formatting will be disabled. You won't have those styles applied.

I have tried updating `editorState` after toggling bold/italic but when `Editor` is focused, but `onEditorStateChange` is returning `editorState` unchanged.

Here is a working [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/rich-text-editor-26moq4) that illustrates the issue.

How can I apply the selected formatting options when the editor is initially focused?